# Use default title text view style for customize title text for AlertDialogs

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-styles

I was needed to create a custom title view to be able show message and title, when the list appears. Because the list appears in the dialog's content area. So the dialog cannot show both a message and a list.

**My custom view** is a LinearLayout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="24dp"
              android:paddingBottom="20dp"
              style="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alert_dialog_custom_title_textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alert_dialog_custom_message_textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Padding values and text size was given in accordance with the information given [material design guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-specs)

[image]

However, This appearance is different from the default one.

[image: screenshots]

**my question**:

- How can I create a textView that has a same style with default one ?

Maybe there is a way like setting a style to my TextView

**Edit** : I just want to set style attribute that makes its visuality same as default AlertDialog.

My textview is already like this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/alert_dialog_custom_title_textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="messsage"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
```

I want to do that just like this :

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/alert_dialog_custom_title_textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="messsage"
        style="?android:attr/titleTextStyle"
        />
```

Comment: android provides sizes for text you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

In your style you can use this

```
<style name="TextAppearance.AlertDialogPro" parent="android:TextAppearance" />
```

for you textview you can add style

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/alert_dialog_custom_title_textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="messsage"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AlertDialogPro"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response. But this is not the answer. As you can see my question, I can already set textview' attributes. This is not what I want. I just want to set style attribute that makes its visuality same as default AlertDialog.

Comment: android:textAppearanceMedium is also  "18sp" which is not right value for default AlertDialog

Comment: I have updated my code you can try that it will work for you.

Comment: I have also updated my question. You can get it what I want.

Comment: I did not understand what do you really want

Comment: I don't want to set attributes of textview hard-coded. I just want to use same style of the default title text view of alertdialogs. I think it is very clear.

Comment: so you want to have all the style what alert dialog uses for your dialog.

Comment: Exactly. for my custom title view.